# Uncaught TypeError: col_class.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

```
$('#addcol-inner').click(function() {
    var sum = 0;0
    var collection = $('#white').find('.ui-sortable-handle');
    collection.each(function(k,v){
        var class_item = $(v).attr('class');
        var col_class = class_item.search('');
        var col_number = col_class.split('-')[2];
        sum += col_number;
        if(sum > 12){

            return false;
    }
```

I dont know whats is wrong, i wont sum the number of col class
this is HTML

```
<div id="white" class="column-container clearfix ui-sortable">
    <div class="column-cell ui-sortable-handle col-md-12" data-post-content-id="3801" data-active-mode="text">
```

Comment: add html part too.also `0;0` seems incorrect

Comment: @AlivetoDie it's probably a typo, although one which affects little.

Answer (score 3):

`search()` returns the integer index of the match, hence `col_class` is an integer value which has no `split()` method.

That line itself is redundant and can be removed as you're searching for an empty string. Also `col_number` will be a string, so presumably you'll need to use `parseInt()` to get the `sum` as an integer.

*Update*

Now that you've added your HTML, the issue is that the column number you're trying to access is the last element in the resulting array, not the second. Hence you need to amend the logic which retrieves that value. Try this:

```js
$('#addcol-inner').click(function() {
  var sum = 0; // note that the second 0 is redundant
  
  $('#white').find('.ui-sortable-handle').each(function() {
    var class_item = $(this).prop('class').split('-');
    var col_number = class_item[class_item.length - 1];
    sum += parseInt(col_number, 10);
    if (sum > 12) {
      return false;
    }
  })

  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="white" class="column-container clearfix ui-sortable">
  <div class="column-cell ui-sortable-handle col-md-12" data-post-content-id="3801" data-active-mode="text"></div>
</div>

<button id="addcol-inner">Click me</button>
```

Comment: the same problem :/

Comment: I don't see how given that the variable no longer exists in my code. Could you please add your HTML to the question

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer for you and added a working example